# Configuring Smart Capture in Landing Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, cloudpage, smart-capture

I created a form on landing page by dragging Smart Capture gear. Smart Capture could validate fields with a few selection, but not exactly what I want. I also want to use a parameter in the browser, so I dragged html gear to try to write AMPSCRIPT like:

```
%%[
   set @mobileURL = RequestParameter("mobile")
]%%

<label>%%=v(@mobileURL)=%%</label>
```

But no luck. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The AMPscript is correct. You’ll need to pass a value in the “?mobile=“ param in your URL for the label to display anything.